# How to hide stuff in template if Current User isn't on their own profile in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a profile page with a button 'edit profile'. however, it shows up for all users when they access the profile. How do I hide/remove it if the profile doesn't belong to the owner??
For example: Alice visits Bob's profile page or vice versa. They can both see 'edit profile' button on each other's page.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'editprofile' %}" role="Edit">Edit
                                Profile</a>'
```

my views

```
@login_required
# profile page
def profile(request):


    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

my model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

[image: profile model]

[image: user model]

Answer (score 0):

add this to template:

```
{% if request.user == varname.user %}
   'whatever u want to hide
{% endif %}
```

add this to views:

```
def profile(request, username):
    varname = Profile.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'varname', varname})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the "edit profile" button based on the profile owner's username. You can compare the username of the profile owner with the username of the user who is visiting the profile page. If the usernames match then show the button, otherwise, hide it using CSS style.

```
{% if request.user == profile.user %}
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'editprofile' %}" role="Edit">Edit Profile</a>
{% endif %}
```

Also, you need to update your view.py file with this:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, username):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user__username=username)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profile': profile})
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it hides the button from the owner too

Comment: Could you please provide your model schema? need to check how you are storing profiles data for users.

Comment: i have it towards the bottom of my post, references from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: url path:('profile/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name="profile"), currently have this: {% if request.user == ownprofile.user %}
                            <a class="btn btn-primary rounded-3" href="{% url 'editprofile' %}" role="Edit Profile">Edit
                                Profile</a>
                       
                            {% endif %}

Comment: this is fine I am talking about models.py structure specifically for the profile model.

Comment: this is all i have for my profile model:
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(
        null=True, default='images/default_pic.png', upload_to="images/"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

Comment: I have updated my answer where I updated the code based on your model. Could you please try and check now?

Comment: still hides it from the current user :\

Comment: do one thing. On your template print out {{request.user}} as well as {{profile.user}} and check what value its giving you

Comment: >>> print(user)
admin
>>> print(profile.user)
admin

not sure how to print request.user

Comment: dont try to print from terminal. add this {{request.user}} and {{profile.user}} to your template HTML file to see the output.

Comment: profile.user comes back blank, request.user = admin

Comment: Ok so this is the issue. Your profile.user doesn't getting data from DB table. can you check your database if the data are getting both table properly?

Comment: i added some pictures of my django admin tables for you to my post